Specifying ResponseSchema when generating content with the Vertex AI SDK (Gemini)
I am attempting to generate JSON content using the Vertex AI SDK (interfacing with Gemini models), where I pass in the structured output ("ResponseSchema") of how the response JSON should be crafted.
Structured Output:
"Comp = {'rank': int, 'score': int, 'propertyId': int, 'address': str, 'proximity': str, 'price': str, 'livingArea': str, 'lotSize': str, 'yearBuilt': int, 'bedrooms': int, 'bathrooms': int, 'notes': str}\r\nReturn: list[Comp]"
C# code:
{
    var prompts = args.Prompts;
    var systemPrompts = BuildSystemPrompts(args);

    try
    {
        var predictionServiceClient = new PredictionServiceClientBuilder
        {
            Endpoint = $"{GeminiLocation}-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
            ChannelCredentials = GetGoogleCredentials()
        }.Build();
        GenerateContentRequest request = new()
        {
            Model = $"projects/{GeminiProjectId}/locations/{GeminiLocation}/publishers/google/models/{GeminiModelId}",
            Contents = { BuildGeminiPromptContents(prompts) },
            SystemInstruction = new Content()
            {
                Parts = { systemPrompts.Select(prompt => new Part { Text = prompt }) }
            },
            GenerationConfig = new GenerationConfig
            {
                CandidateCount = 1,
                Temperature = Temperature,
                MaxOutputTokens = args.MaxOutputTokens ?? MaxOutputTokens,
                TopP = TopP,
                Seed = Seed,
                ResponseMimeType = args.Output == GenAiOutput.Json ? "application/json" : "text/plain",
                ResponseSchema = args.OutputSchema != null ?
                    OpenApiSchema.Parser.ParseFrom(BinaryData.FromBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args.OutputSchema))) :
                    null
            }
        };
        var response = await predictionServiceClient.GenerateContentAsync(request);
        var message = response?.Candidates?.FirstOrDefault()?.Content?.Parts?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text ?? "No Response";
        
        Logging.Model.Instance.LogInformation(LoggingCategory, null, false, $"Gemini Request: Prompts: {string.Join(", ", args.Prompts)}, Message: {message}");
        return new GenAiResponse { Message = message };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.Model.Instance.LogError(LoggingCategory, ex);
        return null;
    }
}

When I execute this code, it throws the following exception:

Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: 'Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.'

I'm not seeing examples online of how to properly specify the ResponseSchema in C#. Does anyone have any guidance for me?

See Schema and this example

@DazWilkin No luck. Even if I pass in the recipe schema from the example, it throws the exception: "Protocol message end-group tag did not match expected tag." It seems like OpenApiSchema.Parser.ParseFrom(BinaryData.FromBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(args.OutputSchema))) isn't the proper way to convert the JSON string to the the ResponseSchema.

As for API reference you may check this public documentation for SDK and client libraries in Generative AI on Vertex AI.
We can install, set up, and use client libraries specifically for C#.
For constructing schema values, various aspects of the API use schemas which are represented using Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Value, which is a generic representation of a JSON value in Protocol Buffers.
Protocol Buffer messages are available for these schemas, and they can be converted to and from Value objects using the ValueConverter class, as shown below.
AutoMlImageClassificationInputs inputs = new AutoMlImageClassificationInputs
{
    ModelType = AutoMlImageClassificationInputs.Types.ModelType.Cloud,
    BaseModelId = "model-id",
    // Other properties
};
TrainingPipeline pipeline = new TrainingPipeline
{
    TrainingTaskInputs = ValueConverter.ToValue(inputs)
};
// Use pipeline in API calls such as PipelineServiceClient.CreateTrainingPipeline.



I'm not seeing how this ML code relates to my question or my code. Your code doesn't use PredictionServiceClientBuilder, GenerationConfig, or ResponseSchema.
